# Acceder a dos campos foreign key del mismo modelo en django

Tags: django, django-models

Despues de horas de busqueda e intentos sin resultados, les pido ayuda.

Tengo dos modelos llamados "Empresa" y "Proyecto".

El modelo Empresa:

```
class Empresa(models.Model):
rut_empresa = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=21, default='Ejemplo: 22.222.222-K', blank=True)
nombre_empresa = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=255, default='Nombre Empresa', blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.nombre_empresa)
```

El modelo Proyecto

```
class Proyecto(models.Model):
nombre_empresa = models.ForeignKey(Empresa, to_field='nombre_empresa', on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                   related_name='nombre', db_column='nombre_empresa')
rut_empresa = models.ForeignKey(Empresa, to_field='rut_empresa', on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                related_name='rut', blank=True)
```

Quiero acceder desde el template Proyecto a los dos campos del modelo Empresa pero ambos modelos me muestran los mismo datos.

Así accedo en el modelo.

```
<div class="form-group col-sm-6">
    {{ form.nombre_empresa }}
 </div>
 <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
    {{ form.rut_empresa }}
 </div>
```

Comment: Primero que nada **no tiene sentido** tener dos relaciones foráneas a un mismo modelo o tabla, basta con una relacion. Por otra parte desde un form no se puede acceder a los campos del modelo `Empresa`, tendría que ser atraves de la instancia, así: `instancia_proyecto.nombre_empresa.campo` o `instancia_proyecto.rut_empresa.campo`.

Comment: Gracias @Julio Cesar, tu Comentas que no podría acceder desde el form en mi témplate?  Me podría comentar cómo hacerlo algún ejemplo (para entender por favor) donde debería instanciar de esa forma? Gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: Cuando me refiero al "form", es a la instancia como tal, no al template en general. Ahora, si el template lo gestiona una `UpdateView`, podrás acceder a la instancia y a sus respectivos campos, de la siguiente manera: `{{ object.nombre_empresa.campo }}`, si es un `CreateView`, no, pues aun no se crea la instancia.

Comment: Si quieres hacerlo en una vista por ejemplo, simplemente has una consulta a la db obteniendo la instancia u objeto, así: `x = Proyecto.objects.get(pk=1)`, y podras acceder a los campos que quieres de la siguiente manera: `x.nombre_empresa.campo`.

Comment: Gracias es un CreateView mañana intentaré lo que indicas.

Comment: Un gusto ayudarte :)

Comment: Julio Cesar probé esto |  x = Proyecto.objects.get(pk=1) y x.nombre_empresa.campo 
 | desde la consola y puedo acceder a los campos :-) para hacer la instancia en la vista (CreateView), tendría que crear una función y hacer la instancia? (perdón por lo básico de la pregunta). Gracias.

Comment: La vista `CreateView` se encarga de crear la instancia, tu no te preocupes por eso, ni lo hagas, pues la vista ya lo hace. En el método [`form_valid()`](http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/3.0/django.views.generic.edit/CreateView/#form_valid) de la vista *(te recomiendo ver el código fuente, para que entiendas mejor)*, se crea la instancia, `self.object` es la instancia creada (si la instancia no se crea aun, el valor de `self.object` es `None`).

Comment: En el método `get_success_url()`, podrás acceder a la instancia y en el método `form_valid()` también (lo ideal seria que lo hagas en el método `form_valid()`), pero tendrás que hacer unas pequeñas modificaciones al método `form_valid()` si lo quieres hacer en el, pero eso ya es otro tema algo extenso de explicar. Lee el código fuente del método `form_valid()`, para que entiendas como funciona y lo podrás hacer sin ningún problema.

Comment: Sera de bastante aprendizaje para ti si lo logras hacer por ti mismo :)

Comment: Ok, gracias me orienta bastante..!! Trabajaré sobre el método form_valid()

Comment: De nada, suerte! :)

Comment: Esto tratando de hacer lo que comentaste y no funciona.
`def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.nombre_empresa.rut_empresa = self.kwargs.get('pk')
        return super(ProyectoCreate, self).form_valid(form)`

Comment: Primero que nada debes obtener la instancia del modelo `Empresa`, con el `pk`, el error te da por que le estas pasando un `pk` no la instancia como tal. Otra cosa es que estas haciendo mal en la relación, aquí: `form.instance.nombre_empresa.rut_empresa`, debería ser así: `form.instance.nombre_empresa`. Entonces finalmente debería quedar así: `form.instance.nombre_empresa. = Empresa.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs.get('pk'))`.

Comment: Por cierto, por favor elimina la relación `rut_empresa` del modelo `Proyecto`, pues no tiene sentido alguno hacerlo, con una relación al mismo modelo es mas que suficiente.

Comment: gracias... tengo que lograrlo jejjeje.
Ya elimine la relación en el campo rut_empresa.

Comment: OK, Suerte!! :)